Why does Windows 11 ignore the Metered Connection setting?
Normally, my laptop is on an unmetered connection, and part of that time, it's on a wired connection with bandpass just shy of a half-gig bps (the rest of the time it's on a Wi-Fi 802.11ac connection that feeds into the same router). However, during the day during the week, it's on a metered Wi-Fi/Mi-Fi connection (an ATT ELEVATE), with a limit of 5GB per month.
For some reason, even though the Mi-Fi is set as a metered connection, it always insists on downloading massive updates while on the Mi-Fi, instead of overnight while on the unmetered connection.
How can I stop this behavior and keep it from abusing my Mi-Fi and costing me extra money on the Mi-Fi every month?

You can try setting the connection metered directly in the Registry. There are settings there that might not be otherwise available, such as setting Ethernet metered, too.


Press Windows, type reged and select Regedit.

Navigate to the following key, e.g., by copying and pasting it into the location bar.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost


Edit the value for that connection type, and for all others, including Default, if need be. The value 1 (hex or dec, makes no difference) indicates normal (unmetered) service, and 2 is for a metered connection.


Note that on some versions of Windows, you might need to change permissions on that key, changing ownership to do so.
N.B. Modifying the Registry can cause serious issues. Make a disk image and/or export that Registry key, before making changes.

Please see the update to the question; if I change the registry setting you describe, it looks like I'd be setting my home Wi-Fi connection - the Wi-Fi that feeds to the same router as the Ethernet - as metered, which I don't want; it's perfectly OK for massive updates to be downloaded on that connection. It's just when I'm connected to the Mi-Fi - which appears to my computer as a Wi-Fi connection - that I don't want it downloading, and I told Windows that that particular network is a metered connection.

@JeffZeitlin, if there is no separate Registry value for Mi-Fi, then it appears there is no way to have Windows provide a separate setting. You might try to create a new DWORD value, if you know the exact name for "Mi-Fi", which might be under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network.

So it appears that one can only set a particular type of connection to be metered or non-metered; the exercise of setting a particular network to metered or not is an exercise in futility, as Windows will happily ignore that setting for any reason that seems good to Microsoft.
